# Why does $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$ converge for $-1 \lt x\lt 1$ if $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Theorem 8.2 of Walter Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis is stated as :

Suppose $\Sigma c_n$ converges. Put $f(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n \ \ \ \ \ \ (-1<x<1)$. Then $lim_{x\to 1} f(x)= \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n$.

I do not understand why does the power series of $x$ have to converge at all.

We cannot apply the comparison test for series here as the terms may be negative for the power series.

Applying Cauchy condition I get :

$|c_nx^n+....+c_mx^n| \leq |c_nx^n|+...+|c_mx^m| \leq |c_n|+...+|c_m|$ for $|x|<1$.

We are not given that $\Sigma c_n$ converges absolutely to bound the first term in the above inequality.

The power series must converge because in an application of the theorem, the following is stated :

> If $\Sigma a_n, \Sigma b_n, \Sigma c_n $ converge to A,B and C resp. and if $c_n=a_0b_n +...+a_nb_0$ then C=AB. Let $f(x) = \Sigma a_nx^n,g(x) = \Sigma b_nx^n,h(x) = \Sigma c_nx^n$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$. For $x<1$ series converges absolutely.

This application is also not clear to me. Please help.

Comment: Is $c_n \ge 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat It does not state that.

Comment: If the series converges then $|c_n|$ is bounded, so $\sum_n c_n x^n$ will converge for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any bounded sequence $(c_n)$  the series $\sum c_nx^{n}$ converges for $|x|<1$ (by comparison with the geomertic series $\sum |x|^{n}$). If $\sum c_n$ converges then  $c_n\to 0$ which makes $(c_n)$ bounded.

Answer (score 2):

You write that you don't understand why $\sum c_nx^n$ converges for $|x| < 1$ because your attempts at using the comparison test and the Cauchy test did not work.  Did you look at the proof of the theorem you mention (Theorem 8.2)?  It is right after the statement of the theorem and shows you a reason the theorem is true.

From the proof in Rudin's book, use partial summation to get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^m c_nx^n = (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n + s_mx^m
$$
for all $x$, where $s_n = c_0 + c_1 + \cdots + c_n$.  Since $\{s_n\}$ converges by hypothesis, the numbers $s_n$ are bounded.  Therefore when $|x| < 1$,
on the right side the partial sums $\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n$ are absolutely convergent by comparison to a geometric series and $s_mx^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$. Thus for each $x$ with $|x| < 1$,
the *right side* converges as $m \to \infty$ so the left side converges as $m \to \infty$.

That proof of convergence when $|x| < 1$ might feel like a bit of a trick if you've never used partial summation to rewrite a series in a more convenient form (this method is useful in other settings, e.g., to prove analogous results involving convergence of Dirichlet series), so instead you could use the proof in Kavi Rama Murthy's answer and copper.hat's comment, which more simply proves a stronger result: $\sum c_n x^n$ is absolutely convergent when $|x| < 1$. To recap: convergence of $\sum c_n$ implies $c_n \to 0$, so $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, and if $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, say $|c_n| \leq C$ for all $n$, then $\sum_{n \geq 0} c_nx^n$ is absolutely convergent for $|x| < 1$ by the comparison test:
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} |c_nx^n| \leq \sum_{n \geq 0} C|x|^n = C\sum_{n \geq 0} |x|^n < \infty.
$$
So the convergence aspect of Rudin's theorem for $|x| < 1$ is true for $\sum_{n \geq 0} b_nx^n$ when $b_n$ is an arbitrary bounded sequence.  Rudin's Theorem 8.2 is actually not just about convergence of a power series for $|x| < 1$, but about its behavior as $x \to 1^{-}$ under suitable hypotheses.  The standard name for Rudin's Theorem 8.2 is "Abel's theorem", which he mentions right before he states Theorem 8.2.